# How to make table with different columns per row?

Tags: tables

I am trying to put the following table in Sharelatex:

[image]

I get how to make basic tables, but tables like the one above I find hard as the columns differ for certain rows. This is de code I have until now:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{|m{4cm}|m{4cm}|m{4cm}|m{4cm}|m{4cm}|m{4cm}}
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Display Format} \\
\hline
&High information-density & Low information-density & \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Number of respondents per treatment}
\label{table:3}
\end{table}
```

However this is not providing me with the table I want and I am really stuck here. Can someone please help me with this one?

Comment: What is your problem, exactly?

Comment: I don't know how to get the columns like in the example?

Comment: Use the `c` specifiers, instead of `m{4cm}` (which will probably make your table too wide unless you're using something like A3paper. So it should begin with `\begin{tabular}{ccccc}`. For `\multicolumn`, you seem to know how to do.

Comment: Thanx for the tip!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sans}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Display Format}& \\ \cline{2-5}
    &\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{High information density}& \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Low information density} &\\ \hline
    Cookie type & Noticeable& Non-noticeable& Noticeable& Non-noticeable& Total \\ \hline
    1\textsuperscript{st} - party cookies&29&17&27&20&93\\ \hline
    1\textsuperscript{st}/3\textsuperscript{rd} party cookies&19&22&23&20&84\\ \hline
    Total& 48&39&50&40&177\\ \hline

    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Number of respondants for treatment}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

and image of table obtained by above code:

[image]

Comment: Thanx a lot for your help!

Comment: Instead `\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{...}` and `\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{...}` is better `\multicolumn{4}{c|}{...}` and `\multicolumn{2}{c|}{...}` respectively. Also columns  spanned by multi columns haven't equal width.

Answer (score 2):

Your table is going to be very huge ... 24 cm wide :)- See if the following is what you looking for:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{|l | *{4}{>{\centering}p{2cm}|}c|}
%{|m{4cm}|m{4cm}|m{4cm}|m{4cm}|m{4cm}|m{4cm}}
\hline
    & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{Display Format} 
        &                                                   \\
    \hline
Cookie type
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{High information-density} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{Low information-density} 
            &   Total                                       \\
    \hline
1\textsuperscript{st} party cookies
    & 29    &   17  &   27  &   20  &   93                  \\
    \hline  
\end{tabular}
\caption{Number of respondents per treatment}
\label{table:3}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanx so much for your help!

Comment: Yes I always try all the suggested solutions I get from users here and just accept the one that is closest to what I need. I hope I answered your question

Answer (score 1):

The following code produces your table. Use `\multicolumn` for spanning several columns. If the four center columns don't have to be of equal width, you don't need the `array` package and the new column type `C`; just use type `c`.

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
{\def\arraystretch{1.2}%
\begin{tabular}{|c|C{2.3cm}|C{2.3cm}|C{2.3cm}|C{2.3cm}|c|}
  \hline
  &\multicolumn{4}{c|}{Display Format}{}&\\
  \cline{2-5}
  &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{High information density}&\multicolumn{2}{c|}{Low information density}&\\
  \hline
  Cookie Type & Noticeable & Non-noticeable & Noticeable & Non-noticeable & Total \\
  \hline
  1st party cookies     & 29 & 17 & 27 & 20 &  93 \\
  \hline
  1st/3rd party cookies & 19 & 22 & 23 & 20 &  84 \\
  \hline
  Total                 & 48 & 39 & 50 & 40 & 177 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{document}
```